# direction of verilog concatenation

Tags: concatenation, verilog

I am a beginner in verilog.

Almost of all examples for concatenation are as the following.

```
wire [3:0] result;
reg  a, b, c, d;

result = {a, b, c, d};
```

Is the following possible, too?

```
wire [3:0] result;
wire a, b, c, d;

{a, b, c, d} = result;
```

Answer (score 6):

The LHS(left hand side) of assignments do allow concatenations.

```
module mod1;

wire [3:0] result;
wire a, b, c, d;

reg e,f,g,h;

{a, b, c, d} = result; //Invalid, not in procedural construct

assign {a, b, c, d} = result; //Valid
assign {a,{b,c},d}  = result; //Valid

initial 
   {e, f, g, h} = result; //Valid

endmodule
```